# how to get the mapped URL from controller name + action name in springmvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is there existing solution to get mapped URL from (controller-name, action-name) in Spring MVC3, like UrlHelper in asp.net mvc or rails? I think it's very useful!

thx....

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are trying to get?

Comment: like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Probably, you want something like this:

in your `@Controller` class, you can add to your "action" method extra parameter of type `HttpServletRequest`.

Example:

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/helloWorld")
    public void helloWorld(HttpServletRequest request) {
        //do call #getRequestURI(), or #getRequestURL(), or #getPathInfo()
    }
}
```

With default configuration, Spring will "automagically" inject request, and then you can extract path info by calling one of `HttpServletRequest#getPathInfo(), HttpServletRequest#getRequestUrl()` methods (see explanation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#method_summary)

Comment: oh...I want to take a url from something like 'a url generator'.....e.g. XXX.link(HelloWorldController.class,"helloworld") ----> "hellowold/helloworld.htm"

Comment: and it can be use in anywhere... I try to find someway in the source file of spring...but it seems that it's not easy to implement it...

Comment: you should explain better then what you really need. my answer is generic one, and with it you could get any path beyond Servlet context path (which is root one defined for your web application like `localhost:portNum/myWebApplicationRootContext/path/beyond/application/context)`